# How to search partially array value in PHP

Tags: php

First of all - thx for ansvers.

I have got 2 arrays:

For example:

```
['a' => abc, 'b' => cde]
```

And second one

```
['fcb' => cde, 'avm' => efg]
```

Need to have true of 'b' and 'cde'.

How get a certain similarity for this?

Comment: `['a' => abc, 'b' => cde]` did you miss quotes?

Comment: updated - sorry!

Comment: And are you talking about the keys or values? This is not clear at all and is likely to be closed.

Comment: Why true for 'b' and 'cde'?

Comment: i whant true bool for 'b' => cde & 'fcb' => cde (in_array and similar does not working!)

Comment: Please, explain the problem. You have two arrays and you do what? Search in them? Or what?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @ZeiZ if in the 2nd array 'avm' => abc ?

Comment: Space and nature magic power tell me that OP searches for `isset` in a manner `if (isset($array[$key])) { ... }`

Comment: `if(isset($arr1['b') and $arr1['b'] == 'cde')` ?

Comment: Read about [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Answer (score 0):

I may be falling into a trap; but, you can compute the intersection (common values) and loop them and search for the key:

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

foreach($result as $val) {
    echo "$val found in array1 at key: " . array_search($val, $array1)."<br>\n";
    echo "$val found in array2 at key: " . array_search($val, $array2)."<br>\n";
}
```

See [Example](https://3v4l.org/TpX8i).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do string search on both keys and values based on your requirement that 'b' should match in both cases:

```
$a = ['a' => 'abc', 'b' => 'cde'];
$b = ['fcb' => 'cde', 'avm' => 'efg'];

function search($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach(array_merge($haystack, array_keys($haystack)) as $value)
    {
        if (strpos($value, $needle) !== FALSE)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

echo (int) search('b', $a);
echo (int) search('b', $b);
echo (int) search('z', $a);
echo (int) search('z', $b);
echo (int) search('cde', $a);
echo (int) search('cde', $b);
```

Output:

```
110011
```